# Installing WSGI on EC2 micro instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, django

How do I install Apache with WSGI on my Amazon AMI EC2 micro instance?

I tried

```
sudo yum install httpd libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

but I got this error message

> no package libapache2-mod-wsgi available

Apache installed successfully. My goal is to run a Django application on this instance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`yum search wsgi`

> ```
> mod24_wsgi.x86_64 : A WSGI interface for Python web applications in Apache
> mod_wsgi.x86_64 : A WSGI interface for Python web applications in Apache
> ```